# Performing a simple digit test to a string

Tags: javascript, string, digit

I've just started my journey in programming and lately I've been learning how to use JavaScript at University. I am stuck on an exercise that I just cannot get my head around!

The question is: Write a digit test without using logical operators [hint: string operators].

So I need a test to see if there are any digits in a string. I've got as far as:

var x=prompt("Enter any characters"); (e.g. hello123)

var y="0123456789";

(I figured that the input should somehow compare to the y variable so I can get an answer)

That's all I got! Hopefully this shouldn't be too complicated. (Can't wait for that "Oh yeah.." moment!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the exact bounds of your  problem are, but you can use a regular expression to check for digits:

```
var x = prompt("Enter any characters");
if (x && x.match(/\d/)) {
    // there are digits in the string
}
```

or written a different way (either is valid):

```
var x = prompt("Enter any characters");
if (x && /\d/.test(x)) {
    // there are digits in the string
}
```

Note, this is also making sure that `x` is non-null and not empty before attempting to use it as a string because if the user cancels the prompt, it will return `null`.

`\d` in a regular expression means to match any digit

You can read about regular expressions in javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and about the string methods that use them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

---

I'm still guessing as to what the real bounds of your problem is, but without regex and using only the functions you mention in your comments, you can do this:

```
var digits = "0123456789";

// get string from user
var str = prompt("Enter any characters");

// check each digit one at a time
if (str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
        // see if the next digit is in the string
        if (str.indexOf(digits.charAt(i)) {
            // found a digit
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can understand what you have coded but unfortunately we haven't been introduced to the "match" function. Perhaps I should have been clearer as to what I have available for solving this problem. I can use the following:

.length, .substr(start,length), .substring(from,to), .indexOf(subs), .lastIndexOf(subs), .indexOf(subs,from), .lastIndexOf(subs,from), .charAt()

Assignment operators can also be used.

Comment: @gsymeoni - Yes, it does make a difference for you to tell us what the actual limitations are.  What does it mean that you can't use logical operators?

Comment: I'm assuming and (&&), or (||), not (!), ASCII

Comment: @gsymeoni - OK, I added another solution using only the functions you mention.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your time, I'll also make sure to read into the links you provided.